# Moving DTOs between server/client

Tags: java, server, hibernate, client

I am developing a server for a web-client. Basically it's just a simple CMS to modify some data. My problem is that I never had a project like this where I have to take care about the server *and* the client and of course everything that happens between those two.

I've started to implement a database with `Hibernate` which is a great tool but it has its learning curve - I can tell. However, the client is also written in Java. Here I am using GWT. The thing now is that my database keeps growing and is getting more and more complex and I am not quite sure if the way I am doing it is sane.

To keep it simple assume we just have e.g. a `Store` that has collections of `Item`, those again have an `ItemDescription` and those descriptions e.g. do have foreign keys to `Language` in order to provide different translations. So far so good.

What am I sending to the client? What I did for now is I built POJO objects that basically are mirror images of the `Hibernate` entities:

```
public class LanguageDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1991918538222888435L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // Getter/setter
}
```

and with `Hibernate`:

```
@Entity
public class Language implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3968717758435500381L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="LANGUAGE_CODE", length=2,unique=true)
    private String languageCode;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="LANGUAGE_NAME", length=50,unique=true)
    private String languageName;

    public Language() { }

    // Getter/setter
}
```

I have done the same to `Store`, `Item`, `ItemDescription` etc. and I am sending the actual IDs from the database to the client and back to the server for persistence routines.

But I didn't stop there. I have also "*mirrored*" the relations between the POJO objects. That means I have basically almost an exact copy of the database on the client side (of course only the data that corresponds to a logged in user).

Is it a good idea to do that?

I personally like this because to me nothing really changes. Since I know the database I have no troubles finding the stuff I need on the client. Another thing that I like is that I e.g. have a map `Map<Long, ItemDescription>` on the client side that mirrors the relation `Language.id` and `ItemDescription`. This is convenient since The client can work with different languages right away.

But here comes the thing that is starting to make me a little wonder if I should do it like that. On the server I have to util classes `ConvertToDTO` and `ConvertToEntity` which have a lot of functions like that:

```
public static Item convertItem(Store store, ItemDTO itemDto) {

    Item item = null;

    Session session = HibernateSession.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    if(itemDto != null) {
        if(itemDto.getItemId() != null) {
            item = (Item)session.get(Item.class, itemDto.getItemId());
            if( item != null ) {
                session.close();
                return new Item(store, itemDto.getAvailable());
            }
        }
    }

    item = new Item(store, false, false);

    session.save(item);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return item;
}
```

which basically converts a DTO POJO into a Entity class. These static functions are using each other:

```
public static Tool convertTool(Store store, Language language, ToolDTO toolDto) {

    ItemDTO itemDto = toolDto.getItem();
    Item item = ConvertToEntity.convertItem(store, itemDto);
    Tool tool = new Tool(store, item);

    toolDto.getItemDescription(language.getId());

    // ...

    return tool;
}
```

which is the downside of the way I decided to do it. I have to have the complete entity data to restore an entity object and e.g. if the user *created* a new `Item` I have to check this:

```
if(itemDto != null) {
    if(itemDto.getItemId() != null) {
        item = (Item)session.get(Item.class, itemDto.getItemId());
        if( item != null ) {
            session.close();
            return new Item(store, itemDto.getAvailable());
        }
    }
}

item = new Item(store, false);

session.save(item);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

and I am not sure if I should do that either like this.

I have the feeling that I'm doing a few things much more complicated than I should. Another question that arises is "how much" data should I send to the client and how to keep track on changes the user is doing to the DTO objects. After all I have to persist the returning DTO objects and in order to do that I have to check and validate everything field by field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In complex projects, it is always a good idea to use domain objects and DTOs. If you use your entities in other layers of your applications, you may sooner-or-later notice problems. And if you are already using them in your whole app, it is difficult to change is afterwards.

- other layers, which are not related to persistence, need to have a dependency on Hibernate
- if you use any other persistence technology, like NoSQL DB, you have to convert them anyway using some Translator. Hibernate and relational databases are just *one* possibility.
- contraints like `NotNull` may be OK for your DB, but are you sure it cannot be null in the UI?
- in other layers, you probably will not need all fields, so you do not need to transfer them to them.

So IMO it is a good idea to translate your objects between the layers. It can be tedious to build parallel objects for each layer, I think it is worth it. Dozer (not intended as spam) is a framework which may help to reduce that (although I have not used it yet).

Converters should just convert, not starting transactions (like in `convertItem()`). You could structure your application using DAOs, repositories and services. See [DAO, Repositories and Services in DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935773/dao-repositories-and-services-in-ddd). Code like `(Item)session.get(Item.class, itemDto.getItemId())` would probably be in a DAO, in an `getById(long id)`-method. Transactions are usually started on the service layer, using declarative transactions like in Java EE or Spring, you don't have to handle transactions manually.

A Service could have a simple method `addItemToStore()`. You could also introduce still a layer between the service and the DAO, but it is a good start for a simple service.

```
@Transactional
public void addItemToStore(Store store, Item item) {

    StoreEntity storeEntity = storeDao.getById(store.getId());
    ItemEntity itemEntity = itemDao.getById(item.getId());

    storeEntity.getItems().add(itemEntity);
    storeDao.save(storeEntity);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Well, `convertItem()` in my case is basically the ugly way to implement a DAO object I guess. You're saying that a convert should not start transactions and I totally agree on that - but I have to e.g. add a new `Item` first and then `ItemDescription` to the database if the user creates a new one because in that case `getId()` from `Item` would return null. Would the DAO object handle that?

Comment: What would `storeDao` return if e.g. `store.getId()` was null like in `storeDao.getById(store.getId());` Would it create a new entry if `store != null`?

Comment: A DAO Object only handles things like save, get, maybe find, but it would not be responsible for creating a new entry.
The method `addItemToStore` assumes that the `Store` and the `Item` are already existing, it only adds the "link" between those entities. You could add other methods for creating `Store`s and `Item`s or a method `createItemAndAddToStore()`, depending on your requirements.

Comment: I'm refactoring right now but I don't get my head around this. I would have to re-implement a lot of functionality like Hibernate `save()`, `saveOrUpdate()`, etc. I am also not sure how this would work for more complex stuff. Would a DAO be able to work with other DAOs and check e.g. if `Item` and `ItemDescription` do exist and if not create them? The little example you showed does not cover all the checking that must go on before calling `save()`.

Comment: If you have complex logic to do before saving, this should not happen in a DAO. You can do that in a Repository, which builds the entity with its collections from the object which it gets from the other layers and then save the entity.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I have been reading a few things about repositories .. the minds diverge on that topic. E.g. http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton right now I am a little helpless though.